# Any downsides to "Employee of the Month" edict?

Tags: tropico-6

As the title states, is there any downside other than the obvious $350/month charge for the edict?  Will the workers have less fun, be more tired, or anything else one should be aware of?

Answer (score 1):

[Source](https://guides.gamepressure.com/tropico-6/guide.asp?ID=49317)

[image]

According to this, which is exactly what the game notes say aswell. The only downside is the fact that you're shelling out $350 per month.

Most edicts will out right tell you the downside or negative aspects of edicts.

Comment: Yes. However, it is also known that workers will leave the workplace when they need rest, they need food, and when they need entertainment. If they work double shifts there will be less time available for that - which might (should) lead to an overall drop in Happiness numbers for Food, Fun, and maybe Job. It's not so easy to confirm however.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but that's the whole point of this particular edict, you're paying a monthly fee to avoid them from complaining from them being overworked. Furthermore, I've never once had to use this edict. 

Why don't you just play a map and run this edict nonstop and see what happens with industrial workers. It should be easy to confirm.

Comment: It should also be noted that this is one of these most expensive edicts in the game. So that should give you a clue that the only negative aspect is the monthly expense. If you have a small industral complex than you'll likely lose money. But if 7 to 8 finished goods industries running, then it might be worth it. But ironically if you had that many finished goods industries, you should be rolling in the money. So you wouldn't need the edict.

Comment: Right :-)  Well the whole point of raising the question here was to seek out, if anyone had already done any in-depth testing for any negatives _apart_ from the obvious $350 monthly charge. I will test it, as soon as I figure out a reasonably controlled way of doing so.

Comment: I've also taken it upon myself to ask this question on reddit on your behalf. https://www.reddit.com/r/tropico/comments/bdqvwo/any_downsides_to_employee_of_the_month_edict/